# Header files are missing from installed location

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, include

Recently I have installed Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 and it seems that there are no header files under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include.

I search the Internet for this problem and the only page I found about that is 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/b8543ffb-7c4f-4b9e-8a6a-0dd195e8f680.

The guy who had the same problem ended up with copying the C++ header files from a friend zip.
Since this is not a pretty good solution, I ask you for help.

What should I do to have this work? (I have Windows 8 OS, but the guy from the forum discussion linked above has Windows 7 so... I don't think this is the problem).

Comment: I found mine in `Program Files (x86)` rather than `Program Files`, are you sure you're looking in the right place?

Comment: I have 32bit OS, I only have Program Files

Comment: Did you try reinstalling VS 2010 Ultimate?

Answer (score 1):

After more search I found this discussion. It seems it is an old strange problem and there are  2 solutions for this: 
1) install a fresh copy of Windows and afresh copy of Visual Studio
2) copy VC folder from a friend who has a good version of Vsiaul Studio installed

Comment: +1 copying a co-worker's VC folder solved this for me. (VS2008)